# Bot counting its own reaction discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been making a reaction menu system and the base is copied off a reaction role things I made, the reaction role works fine but when I copied it to the new bot the bot started counting its own reaction and I have no idea why, I didnt change any of the filters

The reaction code is below

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) =>  { 
   //bot is counting its own reaction
   if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

   if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
   if (user.bot);
   if(!reaction.message.guild) return;  
    
   if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
      if (reaction.emoji.name === reactone) {
         // ...
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to include your filter. Also what's the point of `if (user.bot);`? This has no effect

Comment: I think the point of that was to filter out any bots using it, it seemed to work on the other one I did, the code show is the only filters

Comment: The if statement does nothing since you cut it off immediately. You most likely ment `if (user.bot) return` however its better to implement this behavior in your filter. [If-Else MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: What your code shows is only a listener, if you provide no filters than that's the reason why bot messages are being counted as well. Whenever you create a collector you can pass in a filter as an option. Since you use a general event, apply the `return` to your if-statement

Comment: cool will look into doing these things thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply missed a `return` after this if-statement:

```js
if(user.bot)
```

Just add the `return` statement

```js
if(user.bot) return;
```